# Filter data frame based on date columns pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame as shown below.

```
Unit_ID    Added_Date                   Status         
105        2019-10-02 07:18:18          Rented
106        2020-15-01 07:18:17          Rented
105        2019-10-02 07:18:19          Rented
108        2020-15-01 07:18:18          Vacant
```

From the above I would like to find out the Unit_ID which has been added within last 10 days based on the Date column.

Expected Output:

```
Unit_ID    Added_Date                   Status         
106        2020-15-01 07:18:17          Rented
108        2020-15-01 07:18:18          Vacant
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use the `.dt.days` accessor and compare with [`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) 10:

```
#df['Added_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Added_Date'],format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
df[(pd.to_datetime('today') - df['Added_Date'] ).dt.days.le(10)]
```

---

```
   Unit_ID          Added_Date  Status
1      106 2020-01-15 07:18:17  Rented
3      108 2020-01-15 07:18:18  Vacant
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do:

```
today = pd.to_datetime('today')
n = 10 # last n days

filter_criteria = df['Added_Date'].sub(today).abs().apply(lambda x: x.days <= n)

df.loc[filter_criteria]

     Unit_ID Added_Date           Status
106      106 2020-01-15 07:18:17  Rented
108      108 2020-01-15 07:18:18  Vacant
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using `pd.DateOffset`

```
from datetime import datetime
df.loc[df['Added_Date'] >= (datetime.today() - pd.DateOffset(days=10))]
```

---

```
   Unit_ID          Added_Date  Status
1      106 2020-01-15 07:18:17  Rented
3      108 2020-01-15 07:18:18  Vacant
```